# unable to install using debuginfo-install

Tags: linux, gdb

I'm using oracle linux 7.9
when I try to run

```
(gdb) ls
```

Output is

```
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-120.0.1.el7
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/ls...Reading symbols from /usr/bin/ls...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install coreutils-8.22-24.0.1.el7_9.2.x86_64
(gdb)
```

In last second line it shows me to install missing dependencies
If i try running

```
sudo debuginfo-install coreutils-8.22-24.0.1.el7_9.2.x86_64
```

It says

```
$ sudo debuginfo-install coreutils-8.22-24.0.1.el7_9.2.x86_64
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Could not find debuginfo for main pkg: coreutils-8.22-24.0.1.el7_9.2.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package libacl-2.2.51-15.el7.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package libattr-2.4.46-13.el7.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package libcap-2.22-11.el7.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-21.0.3.el7_9.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package 1:gmp-6.0.0-15.el7.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package libselinux-2.5-15.el7.x86_64
No debuginfo packages available to install
```

I tried searching internet but couldn't find anything that helps.
What should I do to install those packages shown by gdb

Answer (score 1):

Google, **debuginfo packages centos** → http://debuginfo.centos.org/7/x86_64/

> Due to lack of available bandwidth, we currently don't offer rsync to
> download/synchronize content from centos.org for debuginfo pkgs. Also
> worth knowing that this mirror is running on limited available
> bandwidth too.

`coreutils-debuginfo-8.22-24.el7_9.2.x86_64.rpm` :  http://debuginfo.centos.org/7/x86_64/coreutils-debuginfo-8.22-24.el7_9.2.x86_64.rpm

---

Comment: I searched for "debuginfo packages rocky" and found them on downloads.rockylinux.org. Thanks!